# Android ERROR: 9-patch image

Tags: android

Hi all i want to design `ListView` style like with this image:

[image]

then i'm design this below image but i get an error as :

```
Warning:Android Resource Caching: [Tsms] ERROR: 9-patch image /home/tux-world/Desktop/Tsms/res/drawable/sms_content.9.png malformed.
```

My design image is :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your 9-patch can be wrong.

Maybe your strips 9-patches one-pixel borders away and information gained from them is not available. Try to add bottom line and right line for text too. I think it will help to solve your problem.